# Electron APP shows undefined document.body

Tags: javascript, electron

Hello I am using electron to load external URL, in the external url i have the script bellow showing the iframe inside window.open.

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=600,height=400");
myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe allowFullScreen='true'></iframe>";
```

In normal browser it works fine but in electron App I am receiving the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined**

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Electron documentation, `window.open` returns a [BrowserWindowProxy](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window-proxy) object:

> Class: BrowserWindowProxy
>
> Process: Renderer
>
> The `BrowserWindowProxy` object is returned from `window.open`  and
>   provides limited functionality with the child window.

Instead of:

```
myWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe allowFullScreen='true'></iframe>";
```

you may try:

```
myWindow.eval (`document.body.innerHTML = "<iframe allowFullScreen='true'></iframe>";`);
```

Please note the use of the back-tick string notation here to avoid having to escape both single and double quotes, but it's definitely a matter of taste...

HTH...